# "Who moves" MongoDB Reactive Streams Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive, reactor, reactive-streams

I Know that this driver fulfill the "Reactive Streams API" but what kind of Threadpool is in the core of this implementation? for exmaple Redisson use Netty but what is used in this MongoDB Reactive Streams API?

Comment: Did you try reading the [github page](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/)? Seems like there is a [prominent link](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) there. Also you could have always looked at the source for dependencies https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/blob/master/driver/build.gradle

Comment: Hi, first that for your reply :-) !!!, I know that mongo driver implement the "Reactive Streams API" but i don't know what is behind the scenes, i mean, if you see here http://www.reactive-streams.org/announce-1.0.0 there are lot of implementation of this specification, for example i know that akka implement with an actor system and how actor system use the fork-join-pool for thread management, i also know that there are a reactor-netty implementation that use an "event loop" approach but, how is implemented in mongoDB driver??

Comment: @joliva did you get your answer? I am designing a significant architecutre based on reactive paradigma and I have been studing MongoDb as mainly source (kafka streams FireStore Real Database are other stuffs on the table). I didn't understand what is used to reach back pressure control from https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/